# Export page content to PDF using a iTextSharp (include buttons and grids)

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext, html, html2pdf

How to export my aspx page (include buttons and Grids) to PDF?

Searching the web I found [iTextSharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp), but it works only with normal html.
If my page has Grids or Buttons, these do not appear in PDF.

My current code for export to PDF.
This code exports only basic html (no buttons or grids).

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=AllPage.pdf";
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);
GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
GridView1.DataBind();
GridView1.RenderControl(htextw);
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
document.Open();
StringReader str = new StringReader(stw.ToString());
HTMLWorker htmlworker = new HTMLWorker(document);
htmlworker.Parse(str);
document.Close();
Response.Write(document);
Response.End();
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf).  It'll handle anything short of an ActiveX control.

Comment: he needs itextsharp, not webkit.

Comment: Back when this was written, iText{sharp or otherwise} wasn't all that good at HTML->PDF conversion.  It could /do/ it, but not terribly well.  wkhtmltopdf is sitting on top of webkit and can handle just about anything you throw at it, INCLUDING html that is rewritten by javascript (with the right command line options).  You can convert your GMail page to PDF.  It's crazy.

Comment: that is great and it indeed not very well when using itextsharp to convert webpage to PDF.I never use WKhtmltopdf.the best library I use in this issue is Spire.PDF for .NET.it even can convert dynamic advertisement to PDF,and the code is simple. only three lines                                             String url = “Http://apple.com/”;
            doc.LoadFromHTML(url, false, true, true);
            doc.SaveToFile(“webpageaspdf.pdf”);                   you can see this article, that would be very helpful http://pdfcsharp.blog.com/2012/11/25/webpage-to-pdf-save-webpage-as-pdf-with-c-vb-net/